# Is there a way to add close buttons to the scale mode?

Tags: 12.04, tweak, scale-mode

I have just moved back from Linux Mint 14 cinnamon to Ubuntu 12.04. In Linux Mint 14 the scale mode puts an X next to each window and gives the option to close them one by one in scale mode. Can I add the close mode with Compiz Settings Manager in Ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even better (AFAIC), you can set a keybinding or mouse binding (eg wheel click or right click) to close windows.

Check the **Scale Addons** in **Utility**, not **Window Management**, and set up what you want in the **Bindings** tab.